# Which method implementation prefer?

Tags: asp.net

I want to print a string like(MR or MISS + string) when ever enter in the text box, so which method should preferable 
1. Instance method
2. Static method
3. Extension method
which method is best suitable for memory wise also

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Maybe just build it into the class? (if there is one)